# How to log request body on ResponseStatusException in Web Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm trying to implement custom logging for ResponseStatusExceptions (404 errors and similar).

Web Flux already has a default handler([WebFluxResponseStatusExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/handler/WebFluxResponseStatusExceptionHandler.html)) for such exceptions, so I thought to implement my own similar handler and log what I need there. I need to log the method, URI, HTTP headers and request body. The body is the only problem, others could be easily retrieved from ServerHttpRequest.

My bean CustomResponseStatusExceptionHandler:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(-1) // @Order(-1) needed to process exception before default handler
public class CustomResponseStatusExceptionHandler extends WebFluxResponseStatusExceptionHandler {
    
    public CustomResponseStatusExceptionHandler() {
        super();
        log.info("Registered bean CustomResponseStatusExceptionHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof ResponseStatusException) {            
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            String body = getBodyFromRequest(request.getBody());
            log.error("Request body: {}", body);
        }        
        return Mono.error(ex);
    }
    
    private String getBodyFromRequest(ServerHttpRequest request) {        
        return ???;
    }
}
```

Is this even a valid approach to intercept and log 404 errors (and similar)? If yes, then how can I retrieve the request body?